# chat app FCM how to write a payload for both Android/iOS platforms

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm using FCM to send message from device to device by apply code below, its work perfect on all android devices and iPhone SE, other iPhone device (such as iPhone 6S, 7, 8, X) so on has no pop up the notification or alert, is that any payload code that suit for both platforms?.

I had searched a lot difference solutions but still not working, could anyone help me, Thank you.

```
}).then(result => {

  const token_id = result.val();
  //const userNameGet = result[1].val();

  const payload = {

    notification: {
      title : "Message",
      body: `${userNameGlobal} has sent you a message`,
      sound: "default",
      priority: "high",
      icon: "default"
    }
  };

  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload);

}).then(response => {
  console.log('This was the notification feature.');
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> *its work perfect on all android devices and iPhone SE, other iPhone device (such as iPhone 6S, 7, 8, X) so on has no pop up the notification or alert*

This is very confusing. But basing from the post title, you want to know more about sending messages to different platforms.

> *I had searched a lot difference solutions but still not working*

It would be best for you to include the link/solutions you already checked and results in order for the community better help you next time.

With all that said, at first I intended to suggest [FCM v1's Platform Overrides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing_a_message_across_platforms), but noticed that you are using (correct me if I'm wrong) Firebase Admin (or possibly Cloud Functions).

When using the Firebase Admin SDK to send message, there are actually parameters you could use in the payload to specify items unique to each available platforms (Android, iOS, and Web) which is specified in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#defining_the_message):

> **Top-level message parameters**
>
> `android` - An object comprised of fields specific to Android messages. See [Android-specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#android_specific_fields) for details.
>
> `apns` -  An object comprised of fields specific to Apple Push Notification Service (APNS). See [APNS-specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#apns_specific_fields) for details.
>
> `webpush` -   An object comprised of fields specific to WebPush protocol. See [WebPush-specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#webpush_specific_fields) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try read through all refer link~